# Restrict input but allow paste

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to restrict input to hyphens, decimals, and numbers. But I want to also allow for paste since I am using this for long and lat and I will get user errors if everyone manually inputs.

```
function isNumberKeyDecimalHyph(evt){
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode != 46 && charCode != 45 && charCode > 31
    && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
     return false;
  return true;
}
```

How can I use this but also allow users to paste allowed values into the field?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for key values, bind to the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), and update the text in there.

I've also put a [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefpattern) attribute into the input so that it won't be submitted with bad characters.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e =>
{
  const good_re = new RegExp(e.target.getAttribute('pattern'));
  const bad_re = new RegExp(/([^.\-0123456789])/, 'g');
  if(!good_re.test(e.target.value))
  {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(bad_re, '');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^(\d|[.-])+$">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code proposition

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const error = document.getElementById('error');


// only allow 0-9, hyphens or decimal
input.addEventListener('keypress', evt => {
    if(!/[\-\.\d]/.test(evt.key)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    error.innerHTML = ' use only 0-9, hyphens or decimal';
  } else {
    error.innerHTML = '';
  }
});

// in case user paste, check if the number is valid
input.addEventListener('paste', evt => {
    if(!/^[\-\.\d]+$/.test(evt.clipboardData.getData('text'))) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    error.innerHTML = ' paste only valid serial number';
  } else {
    error.innerHTML = '';
  }
});
```

```css
#error {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<span id="error"></span>
```

Regex will need to be improve to match your pattern or to prevent 2 decimal or consecutive hyphens